# Floor supported by nails, is it structurally sound?

Tags: floor, structural, nails

Each time I look under this floor it bugs me; how can so few nails support an entire floor?
Is this standard construction practice?
It is an 80s house in Canada.
[image: Floor supported by nails]

---

New pictures to satisfy your curiosity:
[image]
The Acro is probably there to support the balcony, with the column directly above.
There is a little step between the floors, this must explain the structural decision. As you can see, it is an open floor.

[image]
The other side of the 4-ply doesn't bother me at all.

[image]
On one side, the 4-ply seem to rest directly on the concrete slab. On the other side, I cannot see because of the isolating foam.

Comment: imho no. I would be adding joist hangers to that.

Comment: are you asking about the nails in the metal part or the horizontal joists?

Comment: @depperm presumably the horizontal joists to the right… the ones at about a 15° angle to the beam they're vaguely fastened to.

Comment: I'd definitely go for the hangers - but first I'd try to establish just how far out of horizontal those beams are & if the floor above is at the same angle - or indeed  if the Acro was used to push up that 4-ply beam in the vain hope it would bring the floor with it… & it didn't, or it skewed the 4-ply leading to the gap in the beams to the right. I'd also want to see how the beams on the left marry up. There's so much there we cannot see from a single image - including absolute horizontal/vertical planes. I'd also want to know what's holding the 4-ply up… https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebSMH.png

Comment: That *was* common, but updated codes usually require joist hangers. This would be worth doing, and is an easy DIY task. Top tips: buy, borrow or rent a palm nailer to put in all those joist hanger nails. If you can't get a palm nailer, use a nail holder, ie, https://www.menards.com/main/tools/hand-tools/specialty-hand-tools/tool-shop-reg-nail-guide/2442365/p-1444428089910.htm

Comment: @Tetsujin I added some pictures. For me the question is already answered, but I thought you might like more context anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated. Makes more sense now.

Comment: Those little pneumatic palm-nailers are a God-send when it comes to driving joist hangar nails! You may want hearing protection, though. And be sure to use proper joist hangar nails, not whatever you've got laying about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

imho I would be adding joist hangers to those joists. The nails may had luckily done the job so far - perhaps due to not many people being in the room at once or it's lightly used.

Something like this, but you need to check what is available and accepted in your locality:
[image]

Then you should investigate why the acrow prop is there - I don't think it is just for storage. Is there any evidence of older support beams being removed.

Comment: @Tetsujin too much evidence of bits being removed (check the paint gaps) to even guess the most likely scenario.

Comment: Yeah - sorry I should have voiced that as a more general 'please provide info' comment under the Q itself. I've moved it now.